# Фильтры для the_excerpt

Tags: wordpress

Нашёл в интернете фильтр длинны цитаты, но других фильтров найти не смог
Подскажите, есть ли таковые? И если есть, то с помощью них как-то можно убрать теги `<p>` вокруг цитаты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Изменение длины обрезаемого текста - добавить в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function(){
    return 20;
} );
```

2. Убрать тег p в начале - добавить в functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```